# Calculate distance using geoNear with lookup

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to calculate distance using geoNear based on value from lookup pipeline.

For this I tried as:

```
db.bookDetail.aggregate([
    {
        $geoNear:{
            near: {
                type:'Point',
                coordinates[70.12,20.12]
            },
            distanceField: 'distance',
            key: 'bookcenter.address',
            spherical: true
         }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: 'books',
            localField:'book.id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'bookcenter'
        }
    }
])
```

It gives the bad Value error: MongoError: error processing query

And geoNear cannot be used after lookup , as I need value from lookup to pass to the key of geoNear.

Please let me know how can I calculate the distance.

If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Note: I have latitude and longitude and want to calculate the distance from address present in books collection which is fetched using lookup

Comment: There are several syntax errors in the query presented in the question, is that the actual code?

Comment: Sorry for the error...I have edited now.

Comment: What is the `50` in the middle of the `$geoNear` stage?

Comment: That is the maximumdistance value,  but it is not required over here. So I will edit it.

Comment: I have edited please check whether it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

The `$geoNear` field was designed to efficiently locate point using a geospatial index.  Using it to just calculate distance is a lot of unnecessary overhead.

If you aren't filtering by distance, it will be more efficient to calculate the distance on the client size with a library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/geographiclib